# Weka windows always open in a different workspaces

Tags: 12.04, unity, workspaces

This is how I installed weka 3.6.6:

```
sudo apt-get install weka
```

On 12.04 every time I open weka it starts in the second workspace. If I move it to workspace #1, all the new windows it opens are in workspace #2. If I try and work in the 2nd workspace, new windows are opened in the 1st. There's no way for me to avoid being hassled by weka.

If I use MyUnity to have only 1x1 workspaces, weka opens, I can tell because it appears in the launcher. but I guess it's in an invisible workspace as I can't see the window.

I tried running some arbitrary Game of Life jar using `java -jar GameOfLife.jar` and it opened in the current workspace. No problem.

I tried downloading weka 3.7.6 and running weka.jar directly and it had the original problem too.

This is the contents of `/usr/bin/weka` if it helps.

```
#!/bin/bash

. /usr/lib/java-wrappers/java-wrappers.sh

# default options
CLASS="weka.gui.GUIChooser"
MEMORY="512m"
GUI=""

function usage()
{
   echo 
   echo "usage: ${0##*/} [-m|--memory <memory>] [-h|--help] [-c|--classname <classname>] [options]"
   echo
   echo "Starts the Weka Machine Learning Workbench."
   echo 
   echo " -h,--help        this help"
   echo
   echo " -c,--class <class>"
   echo "             start using an alternative class if no classname is"
   echo "             given, then '$CLASS' is used by default."
   echo 
   echo " -g,--gui <MDI|SDI>"
   echo "            start weka gui as MDI or SDI"
   echo
   echo " -m,--memory <memory>"
   echo "             the amount of memory to use for the Java Virtual Machine"
   echo "             default: 256m (= 256MB)"
   echo 
}


TEMP=`getopt -o hc:m:g: --long help,class:,memory:,gui: -n 'weka' -- "$@"`

if [ $? != 0 ] ; then echo "Terminating..." >&2 ; exit 1 ; fi
eval set -- "$TEMP"

while true ; do
    case "$1" in
        -c|--class) CLASS="$2" ; shift 2 ;;
        -m|--memory) MEMORY="$2" ; shift 2 ;;
        -g|--gui) GUI="-gui $2" ; shift 2 ;;
        -h|--help) usage ; exit 1 ;;
        --) shift ; break ;;
        *) usage ; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done

find_java_runtime openjdk6 sun6 || \
    ( echo "$0: Java not found, aborting." >&2 && exit 1 )
find_jars weka.jar
JAVA_ARGS=-Xmx$MEMORY run_java $CLASS $GUI $@
```

I realize this may sound like a "weka mailing list" question, but the fact that MyUnity 1x1 makes weka completely invisible is probably a unity bug...

Comment: I have no clue why, but I have the same problem in precise.  Until seeing your question I had no idea weka was successfully starting up at all - it just seemed to hang from the command line....  Thanks.  FWIW, I'm using two monitors.  I note some odd problems with google chrome opening up in the wrong monitor at times also....

Comment: I opened this bug in Unity: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1035520

Comment: This seems to be a bug in compiz related to either multi-monitor setups ([Bug #874146 “New windows open on the wrong monitor” : Bugs : Compiz Core](https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz-core/+bug/874146)), or the use of modal windows ([Bug #754508 “Modal dialogs don't appear on the workspace of thei...” : Bugs : Compiz](https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz/+bug/754508)).  So this should probably be closed here in askubuntu since it is a bug and thus out-of-scope.

Comment: How do I go about closing the question without an answer? If you convert the comment with all the bug links into an answer then I can accept that "solution".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in compiz related to either

- multi-monitor setups ([Bug #874146 “New windows open on the wrong monitor](https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz-core/+bug/874146)” : Bugs : Compiz Core),

or

- the use of modal windows ([Bug #754508 “Modal dialogs don't appear on the workspace of their parent window : Bugs : Compiz](https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz/+bug/754508)”).

So this question should probably be closed as "off topic" here in askubuntu since it is a bug and thus out-of-scope according to the FAQ.